# Cloud (central) based VPN options?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-access, cloud

I have a server at a site where I cant use port forwarding due to network NAT'ting.

I have to access this server remotely, so I was thinking about using a cloud based VPN?

Connect my server to the cloud based VPN, and then connect my remote client to this same Cloud based VPN.

Theoretically, the two should see each other?

P.S. I don't want to host the server online, as I don't want it to be internet facing due to sensitive data on this server.

It's been a while since I fiddled with VPN options... and even then it was site to site.

Any ideas on what could work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Theoretically, the two should see each other?
>   Yes
>
> Any ideas on what could work?

OpenVPN, IPSec, WireGuard would all be capable of meeting your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I need a cloud solution tho, something central so that my Nat'ted network can connect out... Site -> cloud <- site, not site to site ?

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand.